# Casting an Enumerable.Empty<>() into another class that implements IEnumerable returns null

Tags: c#, collections, casting, ienumerable, .net-4.8

I have a class that implements IEnumerable:

```
public class A { }
public class B : IEnumerable<A> { }
```

How can i use class B as `Enumerable.Empty<A>()` in this case?
I mean that casting like this `Enumerable.Empty<A>() as B` returns null. Why it does? Should i implement any specific constructor or a method? Or is it an forbidden operation and I should to do it in the other way?

Comment: You might want to read Eric Lippert's post on [representation and identity](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/) and identify which sort of casting you thought you were trying to do. Then consider whether any *arbitrary* `IEnumerable<A>`, including any other class that may have a declaration similar to `B`s, should also be castable to a `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enumerable.Empty<T>()` is [implemented as](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,4d026772cf3399f5):

```
internal class EmptyEnumerable<T>
{
    public static readonly T[] Instance = new T[0];
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Empty<T>()
{
    return EmptyEnumerable<T>.Instance;
}
```

If you remove the optimization to cache the empty array, you could rewrite this as:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Empty<T>()
{
    return new T[0];
}
```

So `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` just returns an empty array of type `T`.

You wouldn't write:

```
B b = new A[0];
```

This doesn't make sense: a `B` isn't an array of instances of `A`.

For the same reason, you can't write:

```
B b = Enumerable.Empty<A>();
```